# Finding factors

Tags: c++, factors

Well I am doing a C++ program and in that I need to find numbers with common factors from an array.I am already doing it in the naive way.

```
int commonFactors(int p, int q){
    int count = 0;

    if(q > p){
        for(int i = 2;i < q;i++){
            if((q%i==0)&&(p%i==0)){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else if(p > q){
        for(int i = 2;i < p;i++){
            if((p%i==0)&&(q%i==0)){
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        count = 1;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Well then my code timeouts for larger inputs. My input range is from 1 to 1000000 for any element in the array. Any clue about how to compute it efficiently?

I have an idea of checking with only prime factors but I am worried about the range in which to check.

Comment: That's a nice piece of code. Does it work as you wish? If not, what happens? Does it fail to build? Does it not produce the correct results? ***What is your question?***

Comment: It timeouts!! @JoachimPileborg

Comment: Well my inputs are from 1 to 10000000. So any clue with that?

Comment: "Timeouts"? I see no timeouts in the code.  I think you need to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The general algorithm you have there is fairly efficient, but it can be refactored better.

Comment: Exactly how it can be refactored @Hayden?

Comment: Look up 'the Euclidean algorithm'.

Comment: Your text says (more or less) *do these 2 numbers have common factors*, while your code says: *how many common factors do these 2 numbers have*. It is simpler to answer first than second... What is your actual requirement?

Comment: I came in here hoping to help (honestly) but I am lost in "what is the actual question?" here. When you say "it times out" - what does that mean? A native (C or otherwise) program can run *forever* with no timeouts.

Comment: Well my question is do these two numbers have a common factor? @SergeBallesta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the sole question is "do these two have a common factor (other than one)", then one option would simply be to compute their greatest common divisor, and check if it is one. The GCD can be computed fairly efficiently (definitely faster than just counting all the way up to your numbers) using the [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm):

```
gcd(a, 0) = a
gcd(a, b) = gcd(b, a % b)
```

Comment: If it is one? Or greater than one?

Comment: It will be 1 if they don't share any common factors (since all integers share 1 as a common factor). If it is greater than 1 then they have do have common factors.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it more efficiently by running the for loop up to "sqrt(p)" (or q, depending on the smaller number of course).
That should speed up things already.

Answer (score 0):

Consider two numbers: 9240 and 16170. Each number can be written down as a product of a (few) prime numbers:

```
9240 = 2*2*3*5*7*11
16170 = 2*3*5*7*7*11
```

From the example above it should be obvious that the total number of *possible* common factors would be the total list of numbers you can create with those operands. In this case the set of numbers `2`, `3`, `5`, and `11` will produce `15` total combinations.

So your code could do the following steps (I'm not going to write the C++ code for you as you should be able to do so easily yourself):

> 1. Split each the number into its prime factors using [Integer factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization)
> 2. Find the complete subset of those primes that are present in each list (don't forget that some may appear more than once in both lists and should be counted as separate ones, i.e. twice)
> 3. Find all the possible numbers you can create by combining the given set of primes

For the last part of this you can see [Dynamic programming](https://www.google.com/?#q=dynamic+programming) for ideas on how to improve its performance **significantly** compared to a *naïve* approach.

Answer (score 0):

First some mathematics: Say A and B are two positive not null integers, let us call C= gcd(A, B) the greatest common divisor of A and B, then if M divises both A and B, M divises C.

So if you only want to know whether A and B have common divisors you just have to check whether C is greater than 1, if you want to know all common divisors (or their number) you have to find all divisors of C.

Euclidean's algorithm to find the GCD of two numbers is based on following property: say B < A, A = P * Q + R is the euclidean division of P by Q, then if R = 0, GCD(A,B) = B, else GCD(A,B) = GCD(B,R) (ref [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm))

Now some code:

```
/* Euclidian algorythm to find Greatest Common Divisor
 Constraint (not controled here) p>0 and q>0 */
int gcd(int p, int q) {
    // ensures q < p
    if (p < q) {
        int temp = p;
        p = q;
        q = temp;
    }
    int r = p % q;
    // if q divises q, gcd is q, else gcd(p, q) is gcq(q, r)
    return (r == 0) ? q : gcd(q, r);
}

bool sharedivisors(int p, int q) {
    int d = gcd(p, q);
    return d > 1;
}

int divisors(int p, int q) {
    int d = gcd(p, q);
    if (d == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=2; i<d/2; i++) {
        if(d % i == 0) {
            int j = d/i;
            if (j > i) count += 2;
            else {
                if (j == i) count += 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return count + 2; // and 1 and d
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Counting factors from 2 to bigger input is brute force and lasts long even if one of the inputs is large.
Number of common divisors could be get from exponents of their prime factorization. Easier to calculate their greatest common divisor first

```
gcd = gcd( p0, q0 )
/* .. */
int gcd( p0, q0 )
{
    while( q0 )
    {
        int swp = q0;
        q0 = p0 % q0;
        p0 = swp;
    }
    return p0;
}
```

and then count its divisors

- in naiv way (as in question)
- by always dividing gcd with found divisors
- by prime factorization

  ```
  p0^x0 * p1^x1 * .. * pN^xN = gcd
  count = (1+x0) * (1+x1) * .. * (1+xN)
  ```

Prime factorization requires prime list up to sqrt(gcd).